# Colapsar textos em uma única linha numa base de dados

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponha que eu tenha os seguintes dados

```
tabela<-structure(list(nome = structure(c(2L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 
                                       5L, 7L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("12 Anos de EscravidÃ£o", "A CaÃ§a", 
                                                                     "Ela", "Gravidade", "O Hobbit: A DesolaÃ§Ã£o de Smaug", "O Lobo de Wall Street", 
                                                                     "Os Suspeitos", "Rush: No Limite da EmoÃ§Ã£o", "The Avengers - Os Vingadores", 
                                                                     "The Grand Budapest Hotel", "Uma Aventura LEGO"), class = "factor"), 
                    ano = c(2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
                            2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L)), .Names = c("nome", "ano"), row.names = 240:250, class = "data.frame")
```

Como faço para colapsar a coluna de texto "nome" para que meu data frame fique da seguinte  forma:

```
    ano  quantidade nomes
    2012    2       A Caça, The Avengers - Os Vingadores
    2013    7       O Lobo de Wall Street, 12 Anos de Escravidão, Rush: No Limite da Emoção, Ela, Gravidade, O Hobbit: A Desolação de Smaug, Os Suspeitos
    2014    2       The Grand Budapest Hotel, Uma Aventura LEGO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer com o `dplyr` usando a opção `collapse` do `paste`:

```
library(dplyr)
tabela2<-tabela %>% group_by(ano) %>% summarise(quantidade = n(),
                                               nomes = paste(nome,collapse=", "))
```

Por curiosidade vou colocar também o `plyr` (mas o `dplyr` é mais rápido).

```
library(plyr)
tabela2<- ddply(tabela, .(ano), summarise, quantidade=length(nome), nomes=paste(nome, collapse=","))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode também usar o pacote sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
tabela2 <- sqldf("SELECT ano, count(nome) as quantidade, group_concat(nome) as nomes 
             FROM tabela 
             GROUP by ano")
```