# R filtrar conjuntos

Tags: r, data.frame

estou a dar os primeiros passos na programação e com a linguagem R e tenho a seguinte duvida

Eu tenho um dataframe de aniversarios com o seguinte formato

### Meses | Pessoa

Abril  Joao

Março  Ana

Abril Carlos

Junho  Joana

Março  Pedro

e queria um output do genero

Março - Ana, Pedro

Abril - Joao ,Carlos

Junho - Joana

Eu estou a usar unique(df$meses) e consigo os meses unicos mas não estou a conseguir para cada mes selecionar todas as pessoas

estava a pensar guardar os indices de cada unique(df$meses) e depois selecionar os nomes desses indices...isto para cada unique(df$meses). Mas isto não me parece ser muito "correcto" a nivel de optimização.

Alguem pode ajudar?

Obrigado :)

Comment: Rookie, seu problema me parece similar ao desta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11442/colapsar-textos-em-uma-única-linha-numa-base-de-dados/11443#11443

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para esse caso seria usar a função `aggregate`.

```
dados <- read.table(text='Meses Pessoa
Abril Joao
Março Ana
Abril Carlos
Junho Joana
Março Pedro', header = T)

dados_agregados <- aggregate(Pessoa ~ Meses, FUN = function(x) { paste0(x, collapse = ', ') }, data = dados)
dados_agregados

apply(dados_agregados, 1, function(x) { cat(sprintf('%s - %s\n', x[1], x[2])) })
invisible(apply(dados_agregados, 1, function(x) { cat(sprintf('%s - %s\n', x[1], x[2])) }))
```

Note que no segundo não aparece o `NULL` após a tabela. Caso queira salvar em um arquivo .CSV, tu pode usar o write.csv2 (o 2 indica que será no formato brasileiro/europeu)

```
write.csv2(dados_agregados, 'Aniversarios.csv')
```